# iPhone: Navigation Bar button indefinitely links to it's own view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, uinavigationbar

When I navigate from the root view to another view, it works. However, when I want to get back, the navigation button links to itself. This goes on for about 6 taps, until it eventually goes back to the root view.

This only occurs on one view, and the rest are working fine.

I have no idea what code is causing this, but if you need any code, I will amend this post with it. Just ask for it.

Thanks a lot,
Jack.

**Pushing the view (in rootviewcontroller.m)**

*In didSelectRowAtIndexPath method*

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //CSS
    if ([[arryClientSide objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"CSS"])
    {
        CSSViewController *css = [[CSSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CSSViewController" bundle:nil];
        [css setTitle:@"CSS"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:css animated:YES];
    }

    //HTML
    if ([[arryClientSide objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"HTML"])
    {
        HTMLViewController *html = [[HTMLViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HTMLViewController" bundle:nil];
        [html setTitle:@"HTML"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:html animated:YES];
    }


    //Apache
    if ([[arryServerSide objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Apache"])
    {
        ApacheViewController *apache = [[ApacheViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ApacheViewController" bundle:nil];
        [apache setTitle:@"Apache"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:apache animated:YES];
    }

    //JS
    if ([[arryClientSide objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"JavaScript"])
    {
        JSViewController *js = [[JSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"JSViewController" bundle:nil];
        [js setTitle:@"JavaScript"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:js animated:YES];
    }

    //PHP
    if ([[arryServerSide objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"PHP"])
    {
        PHPViewController *php = [[PHPViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PHPViewController" bundle:nil];
        [php setTitle:@"PHP"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:php animated:YES];
    }

    //SQL
    if ([[arryServerSide objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"SQL"])
    {
        SQLViewController *sql = [[SQLViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SQLViewController" bundle:nil];
        [sql setTitle:@"SQL"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:sql animated:YES];
    }

    //HTML Colour Codes
    if ([[arryResources objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"HTMLColourCodes"])
    {
        HTMLColourViewController *htmlcol = [[HTMLColourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HTMLColourViewController" bundle:nil];
        [htmlcol setTitle:@"Colours"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:htmlcol animated:YES];
    }

    //Useful Resources
    if ([[arryResources objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Useful Resources"])
    {
        UsefulViewController *useful = [[UsefulViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UsefulViewController" bundle:nil];
        [useful setTitle:@"Resources"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:useful animated:YES];
    }

    //About
    if ([[arryResources objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"About"])
    {
        AboutViewController *about = [[AboutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:nil];
        [about setTitle:@"About"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:about animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: How are you pushing the problematic view?

Comment: Perhaps the view is pushed multiple times. You could view the `viewControllers` to check this.

Comment: I've fixed a big part of it now. I had copied and pasted that code multiple times, and forgot to change the value of isEqual for all of them. So now, when I try and go back to the root view, I only have to tap on the navigation button titled "CSS", and then when I've done that, I can go back to the root view :-) Any ideas on the last problem?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean with "tap on the navigation button titled 'CSS'". Could you elaborate?

Comment: One view is called CSS, and the navigation button on the navigation bar inherited this view name.

Comment: I've updated my origninal post with the full code in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.